# R peakPick for calculating valleys

Tags: r

I analyze  time series of largely sinusoidal form. I have successfully used peakPick in R to calculate the Peaks in the time series. However the valleys present a problem. Basically I use:

```
smoothpeaks = filter(ts2[,2], rep(1/20, 20), sides=2)
```

to create relatively uniform peaks and valleys. I then use:

```
peakhits <- peakpick(matrix(smoothpeaks,ncol =1 ),
                     neighlim = 10,
                     deriv.lim = 0.04,
                     peak.min.sd = 0.5,
                     peak.npos = 10L,
                     mc.core = 1)
```

to obtain the peaks which correspond to the expected values.
I have tried to use a minus sign before the matrix as that works in some other solutions but not here.
Would appreciate any hints on obtaining the time counts for the valleys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to answer with example data and a clearer explanation of what output is needed. Assuming all you want is the length (duration) of the valleys, you can get them with `rle()`

```
#create some example data
t <- seq(5,25, .1)
smoothpeaks <- sin(t)

# find peaks
peakhits <- peakPick::peakpick(matrix(smoothpeaks,ncol =1 ),
                     neighlim = 10,deriv.lim = 0.04,
                     peak.min.sd = 0.5, peak.npos = 10L, mc.core = 1)

# check number of peaks
sum(peakhits)

# plot peaks found
plot(t, smoothpeaks)
points(t*peakhits, peakhits, col='darkred', pch=19, lwd=10)
```

[image: sinusoid with peaks in red]

Then, using `rle()` you can get the length of contiguous sequences without peaks

```
rle(peakhits[,1])
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:7] 29 1 61 1 62 1 46
#   values : logi [1:7] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...

# Or to extract only the length of the valleys
Filter(function(x) x>1, rle(peakhits[,1])$lengths)
# [1] 29 61 62 46
```

Conversely, you may be interested in the time when a peak occurs (especially interesting if the time interval is not constant):

```
t[peakhits]
# [1]  7.9 14.1 20.4

# And you can deduce the duration of the valleys by a subtraction
diff(t[peakhits])
# [1] 6.2 6.3
```

**EDIT**: if you want the local minima, aka the negative peaks, you can get that byh multiplying by `-1`:

```
t <- seq(5,25, .1)
smoothpeaks <- 1+sin(t)  # adding an offset to make things more interesting

# this time I give a matrix with 2 columns
peakhits <- peakPick::peakpick(matrix(c(smoothpeaks, -smoothpeaks),ncol =2 ),
                               neighlim = 10,deriv.lim = 0.04,
                               peak.min.sd = 0.5, peak.npos = 10L, mc.core = 1)

plot(t, smoothpeaks)
# plot first column (maxima)
points(t*peakhits[,1], smoothpeaks*peakhits[,1], col='darkred', pch=19, lwd=10)
# plot second column (minima)
points(t*peakhits[,2], -peakhits[,2]*smoothpeaks, col='darkgreen', pch=19, lwd=10)
```

[image: both max and min]

```
#and the location of the peaks
t[peakhits[,1]]
# [1]  7.9 14.1 20.4
t[peakhits[,2]]
# [1] 11.0 17.3 23.6
```

Comment: Thanks. However I still do not get the timings of the valleys which should be around 11, 17 and 24 approx.

Comment: And what timings do you get? I can't test without data.

Comment: I think we can work with the example you have provided. From your own graph the values should be 11, 17 and 24 approx for the valleys. How does one calculate the valleys?

Comment: Oh, you want the local minima? Then you can just take multiply `smoothpeaks` by `-1` to invert the curve, and look for maxima. I'm editing the answer. If what you want is the center of the valley, then just take the mean of `t` between consecutive peaks.